# How to change "shipping information" label in magento while registration and checkout process

Tags: magento

I want to change "Billing Information" label text to "Shipping and Billing Information". I tried using Mage_Checkout.csv but this didn't help.

Kindly suggest the solution!

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the **translation file translate.csv** in your theme.
For demonstration purposes, I will use the default theme in the default package (app/design/frontend/default/default). You may apply the steps below to your custom theme.

How to change the label using the translation file:

1. Open app/design/frontend/default/default/locale/en_US/translate.csv
2. Add a new line:

   ```
   "Billing Information","Shipping and Billing Information"
   ```
3. Verify that your Store View uses the correct locale ("en_US").

   Log in to the Magento backend and navigate to System > Configuration > General > General > Tab "Locale Options". The "Locale" has to be set to "English (United States)" (either by directly setting it for the particular Store View or by inheriting from the Website / Default configuration).
4. Verify that your Store View uses the default/default directory. This can be set in System > Configuration > General > Design. By default, "default/default" is used.
5. Refresh or deactivate the cache.
6. Navigate to the checkout page. The label text now should be "Shipping and Billing Information".

How to change the text only for Mage_Checkout texts:

1. If you want to change "Billing Information" only in these places where the checkout translation helper is used, you can modify the line in translate.csv like this:

   ```
   "Mage_Checkout::Billing Information","Shipping and Billing Information"
   ```

Comment: Can you help me, how could I solve almost the same issue in Magento 2 OPC with checkbox labelled by "My billing and shipping address are the same" ? I would like to translate it, I placed the translation in the hu_HU.csv but it didn't changed... I was ran "bin/magento cache_flush" too, but nothing happened... I think something wrong with ajax calls...