# Magento: How can I change the shipping method title at the checkout page?

Tags: magento, checkout

Basically what I'm trying to do is on the Checkout Page, I'm trying to change the USPS 'First-Class Mail Parcel' to 'First-Class Mail Parcel (3-5 Business Days)', 'Priority Mail' to 'Priority Mail (2-3 Business Days)' and 'Express Mail' to 'Express Mail (Next Business Day)'.

Already tried using the translate.csv solution suggested in the below link. For some reason, it only changes the UPS text, but leaves the USPS unchanged.

[How to change "shipping information" label in magento while registration and checkout process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646041/how-to-change-shipping-information-label-in-magento-while-registration-and-che)

Also tried using Translate inline via the Admin Panel, but couldn't get it to work. Hated that function anyways. The book keeps moving whenever you move your mouse making it very difficult to click the box.

There has to be a way to change this...Any help would be appreciated. Been searching Google and the forums for a couple hours now for such a seemingly simple fix.

Comment: Why you don't use the standard way? Admin->System->Configuration->Shipping Methods -> USPS (UPS) -> Title . Does it work for you?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. That only changes the header of whether or not it is USPS or UPS. It doesn't change the 'Allowed Methods' or more specifically, 'First-Class' etc.

Answer (score 1):

To change the shipping methods title of **USPS** methods just go to this file `app\code\core\Mage\Usa\Model\Shipping\Carrier\Usps.php`  and in `getCode()` function you will find various title of **USPS** shipping methods from here you can change title.

Comment: This is modifying magento core and is bad practice and not recommended. Yes it may solve the issue till the user tries to upgrade or apply any patches.

Answer (score 0):

Refer below link. using you can do your requirement. i also done.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/webshopapps-matrixrate-1-multiple-table-rates-extension-certified-bug-free.html

from this module you can upload CSV file for store view wise.